# How to embed a Java Applet from another website (can't link their class file and jar)

Tags: java, applet

In addition to what my title says, I am running into problems because their class file is linked as follows:

```
"var attributes = 
  {code:'xx/xxxx/xx/xx/xxx/xxx/xxxxx.class' 
                       width:645,height:443,archive:'xxxxx.jar'}"
```

First, I naively copied the HTML code and it did show a Java Applet Object, but couldn't load it because it obviously didn't find the class. I tried many different addresses to see if I can download the class, but with no success. Does this mean the class can't be downloaded? I'm in the process of asking for their permission and see if we can get it directly from them.

I also thought of another way. Is it possible to embed their whole page as an iframe AND "crop" it so the iframe only displays the area where the Java Applet is located? If this is possible, it would be the best and easiest way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly can download the the `.jar` file - they have to be accessible so that browsers can load them. I'd guess you are trying to get the `.class` file, but it is within a `.jar`, so get the `.jar` instead.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Before you answered I did that it's all working now. Thanks anyway.