# Whether hotlinking of java applets is possible?

Tags: html, applet, hotlinking

Similar question had been added earlier: [How to embed a Java Applet from another website (can't link their class file and jar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416490/how-to-embed-a-java-applet-from-another-website-cant-link-their-class-file-and)

however someone who asked question didn't need hotlinking in fact.

My applet will not be able to run in other environment than own.

Whether `iframe`s are my last hope?

Comment: At what URL can we visit this applet?

Comment: BTW - I'm still not clear after reading your question, the linked thread, & your question again.  Are you trying to rip someone's applet, or prevent people from ripping yours?

Comment: This is my applet. However I want to prepare it for my customer for some commercial campaign. I prefer host my applet on my own server, because it weights ~1.3 MB, and I am sure, that my server is able to handle traffic which will be generated by my customer. However my customer prepare a whole website, where applet should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hosting an applet from another web site can be as easy as setting an appropriate `codebase` attribute.  E.G. [The properties applet](http://pscode.org/prop/) at my site (view the HTML source for the gory details) can be launched locally (or from another site) using this HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<title>
Property Probe - applet
</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js">
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var attributes = {
    code:'org.pscode.tool.property.PropertyProbe',
    codebase:'http://pscode.org/lib',
    archive:'propprobe.jar',
    id:'applet',
    scriptable:'true',
    width:'600',
    height:'300'
};
var version = '1.2';
var params;
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<script type='text/javascript'>
deployJava.runApplet( attributes, params, version );
</script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

It will run into problems if the applet expects to find (non class) resources relative to the document base, as opposed to the code base.

Comment: I think, this is what I was looking for. However I've noticed, that you are using jnlp files. ASAIK, those kind of files are used in case of JS <-> Applet communication (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html).

Is there any chance to take a look for code of your applet, like into an example?

Comment: @noisy: That was just an applet I chose at random.  It does not need to include JavaScript or JNLP in any form.  Did you try it at home/work with your own applet, or are you waiting for me to post an e.g. using an applet that has your exact specification?  If the latter, I'll need to know the exact specs. before I can proceed, but you might try the former - much quicker.  ;)